# To make a keyboard shortcut for Info in Zsh?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, zsh

Zsh has the following keyboard shortcut for Man

<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>

I would like to have a similar keyboard shortcut for info such as

<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

**How can you make such a keyboard shortcut for Info?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
function run_info() { 
  # Prepend "info" to the command line and run it.
  BUFFER="info $BUFFER"
  zle accept-line
}

# Define a widget called "run_info", mapped to our function above.
zle -N run_info

# Bind it to ESC-i.
bindkey "^[i" run_info
```

Just cut'n paste that into a shell to try it out, and add to your .zshrc for permanent effect.

To paraphrase the code: the general idea is that we first define a widget called "run_info", implemented with a function with the same name.  It takes the command line buffer and adds "info " to the beginning.  Then it accepts the command line (same as pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>).  Finally, the widget is mapped to the keyboard shortcut.

You can read the zshzle(1) man page for more info on how this stuff works.