# In zsh how do I bind a keyboard shortcut to run the last command?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I frequently find myself wanting to repeat a command, and while `!!` is useful, I'd like to bind that to ctrl-w or something like that. Is there a way to do that?

> EDIT: I'm aware that the up arrow does what I want, however I would rather not have to leave the home row. Being an avid Vim user has taught me the value of staying on the home keys.

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836572/to-make-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-info-in-zsh) about adding a shortcut to access the `info` command and tried to extrapolate something out of it, but had no success. Zsh yelled at me about zle not being active or something.

I know this will rely on knowledge of how my shell is configured, so below I've pasted some relevant code, as well as a link to my entire .zshrc and dotfiles in general.

```
# oh-my-zsh plugins. zsh-aliases and drush are custom plugins.
plugins=( git z tmux web-search colored-man zsh-aliases drush)
ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART=true
#... $PATH, start background process (clipboard integration for tmux, 
# glances system monitor), history options, editor, all truncated for brevity.
# use vim mode
bindkey -v
#show insert/normal mode in prompt
function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
    RPS1="${${KEYMAP/vicmd/NORMAL}/(main|viins)/INSERT}"
    RPS2=$RPS1
zle reset-prompt
}
zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N zle-keymap-select
# rebind ctrl-r
bindkey -M vicmd '^R' history-incremental-search-backward
bindkey -M viins '^R' history-incremental-search-backward
```

Full configs: https://github.com/yramagicman/dotfiles

Just the .zshrc: https://github.com/yramagicman/dotfiles/blob/master/.zshrc

custom plugins:

- https://github.com/yramagicman/drush-zsh-plugin
- https://github.com/yramagicman/zsh-aliases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the last command from the history you can use the `up-history` widget. This is by default bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in *vicmd* mode, so pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> (which invokes the widget `accept-line`) would do the trick.

If you want to bind it to a single shortcut, you have to write your own widget. You can add this to your `~/.zshrc`:

```sh
# define function that retrieves and runs last command
function run-again {
    # get previous history item
    zle up-history
    # confirm command
    zle accept-line
}

# define run-again widget from function of the same name
zle -N run-again

# bind widget to Ctrl+X in viins mode
bindkey -M viins '^X' run-again 
# bind widget to Ctrl+X in vicmd mode
bindkey -M vicmd '^X' run-again
```

For the example I chose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> as shortcut because by default it is unbound in *vicmd* mode and self-inserts in in *viins* mode, whereas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is already bound to `vi-backward-kill-word` in *viins*. Of course you could overwrite the default binding if you do not use it anyway or bind the widget only in mode.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Ctrl-X is my tmux "leader," so that doesn't work for me. I've got it bound to ctrl-w for now, but I'll have to look at the Zsh keymap and see if there's a sensible option that doesn't overwrite an existing shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Alternative that doesn't break <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> search:

```
accept-line() { [ -z "$BUFFER" ] && zle up-history; zle ".$WIDGET"; }
zle -N zle-line-init
```

Redefine default <kbd>Enter</kbd> command so it inserts last command if the buffer is empty. Inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166266/144642).

---

**ORIGINAL:**

I have this in my `.zshrc`:

```
last_if_empty() {
  [ -z "$BUFFER" ] && zle up-history
  zle accept-line
}
zle -N last_if_empty
bindkey -M viins '^M' last_if_empty
```

It remaps <kbd>Enter</kbd> to `Run last command` if nothing has been typed on the screen.

Unfortunately it seems to break <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> search (Enter key doesn't work). I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> so it doesn't bother me, but might be  a dealbreaker.