# Can I prevent a terminal command from being run twice in a row?

Tags: shell, zsh

I have a script that does a lot, setting up a new development server, pushing source to it, putting sample data on it, synchronizing the name of the server with my current `git` branch.

Then, once it's set up, I have an alias that pushes new source code to it.

I run the first command a few times a day. I run the alias all the time. And my muscle memory has me making a change to the source, going to the terminal, pressing the up arrow, and pressing return. 90% of the time, this is exactly what I want.

But, after setting up the server, and then making a change to the code, that muscle memory is betraying me, and I end up starting to spin up a new development server. Yes, I just press Ctrl-C to stop it, but it's still annoying.

Is there any way to prevent the server setup command from being run twice in a row?

Comment: why don't u do checks to see if server is running?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using something like Ansible instead of reinventing it.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial, Because I'm the maintainer of the repository, working with PRs, testing them all on new development servers. I might have three or more that I'm working with in any given day.

Comment: @chepner, I just looked into Ansible, and I don't think it would work for my particular environment. I didn't mention because I didn't think it relevant to the problem, but these are all Salesforce scratch orgs. But I'll investigate a bit further.

Comment: You could create a lock file which is created during startup and deleted once stopped. At the beginnend of your script you do some check if file exists. You can of course lookup the Server running as well with e.g. ps command and decide based of that outcome.

Comment: Not sure that I don't understand your question: Do you want to ensure, that if the server is already running on your host, a new server can't be started?

Comment: just automate with: https://eradman.com/entrproject/ and add checks for ensuring the server was started. this way "on save -> check&push"

Comment: @user1934428, my question has nothing to do with whether the server is running. I _always_ have multiple dev servers running, one for the PR I'm working in, one for the PR I'm reviewing, and then I'll go back to the PR I'm working in, then another PR comes in for review and I spin up a new server for that. I just don't ever want to run this one particular command twice in a row. If my muscle memory tries to do that, I want the shell to prevent it.

Comment: Now it gets tricky. What exactly does it mean: _twice in a row_. So, `start_server; start_server` should be caught (the second one should not start the server), but `start_server; echo foo; start_server` should start the server twice?

Comment: @user1934428, effectively, yes. Generally I run `scratch`, my script (which doesn't start _the_ server, but creates a new dev server for me to work with the current PR in isolation), once, and then run `sf-push`, my alias, many, perhaps dozens, of times. I my muscle memory is going to terminal, up arrow, return. But if I just ran `scratch`, up arrow, return executes _that_ and I _never_ want that to happen.

Comment: If it is just the "up arrow", then it is a different problem. You would have to ask "how do I prevent _scacth_ being entered in the zsh history". But according to your writing, you also want to catch the case that you enter the command twice in a row by explicitly typing it. There is a solution for this too, but it is more complicated than just blocking it from the history.

Answer (score 1):

If you are feeling adventurous, you can rebind your enter key to use this widget

- If the current buffer is empty, it repeats the last command.

  - However, if the last command is "ls" (replace with your command), it does not repeat it.
- If the current buffer is not empty, then it just runs the standard accept line widget (.accept-line) to execute whatever you have typed in your prompt.

```
accept-line() { 
  if [ -z "$BUFFER" ]; then
    local prevCommand=$(fc -ln -1)
    if [ $prevCommand = "ls" ]; then
      # do nothing
    else
      zle up-history
    fi
  fi
  zle ".accept-line"; 
}
zle -N accept-line
```

[In zsh how do I bind a keyboard shortcut to run the last command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819359/in-zsh-how-do-i-bind-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-run-the-last-command)